# KO3 Auth module - Subdomains

Tags: kohana, subdomain, authentication

I use **Auth module**, but it works only for a **subdomain**, where I am logging in.. For example, my login page is on **www.domain.tld**, and after login, there is always logged user. But on **subdomain**.domain.tld, there is not. I changed property domain in **Kohana_Cookie** to .domain.tld, but without effect..

Could you help me?

Comment: Does your subdomains uses different directories to store session data?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.domain.tld');` to `bootstrap.php`.